# how to call function from one of the module inside a package without mentioning modules name?

Tags: python, module, package, namespaces

I've got `callMe()` inside `mypack.py`. But to make things clear I've moved my functions to separate module

```
|mypack
  |__init__.py
  |mycalls.py
  |...
```

but i want to keep how they were called before that changes:

```
import mypack
mypack.callMe()
```

is there proper way to do this?

i know that it could be done with `__init__.py` using import all but is that a good practice?

```
from .mycalls import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, I'm not quite sure why this would be helpful or in which use case this could be beneficial, if you insist on calling `mypack.mycalls.*` as `mypack.*` you can simply do:

```
import mypack.mycalls as mypack
```

Then you're able to do:

```
mypack.callMe()
```

Comment: @bafly there is no real "proper" way for this. It is unusual to keep the `mypack.callMe()` reference after refactoring your mycalls into mypack. If you need to keep the original call, then I would suggest modifying the import statement, as I've pointed out above. If your mypack is a small package you might be able to do this in the __init__ method anyways which would clean up your import statements and calls.